# Is that possible to run a python built program on iOS as a static lib?

Tags: python, ios, binary, static-libraries, cross-compiling

I have some AI code developed in python 2.7 that uses non-standard libraries.

I intend to compile it to work with my iPhone app.

I wouldn't like to re-program everything so, is that a way to compile my python code + all dependencies into a static file so I can call it from my iOS app as a function?

Comment: Are the non-standard libs open source?

Comment: @marcelosalloum I am trying to use https://github.com/yann2192/pyelliptic  library, but proper documentation is not mentioned in kivy.Could you please tell me steps for the same?

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal, I've never managed to make it work. It was pretty immature at the time, I couldn't make it work and never tried again. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

kivy can do it

http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

also maybe look at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/python-for-ios/id485729872?ls=1&mt=8

although I doubt you can just compile your existing project into it... you will need to re-write at least part of it and you can only use pure python libraries (kivy)

Comment: If I use a solution with [Python 2.7 for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/python-for-ios/id485729872?ls=1&mt=8) I'd need the user to have it installed, right? Therefore I woudn't relie on this option. Have u ever used Kivy? Does it really do the work?

Comment: Ive used it with android and it runs like a native app ... I havent had experience in IOS with it but I assume its the same ... its kind of difficult to set up but once you get your environment setup it just works

Comment: I coudn't compile the distribution version and got the following error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905622/failed-to-compile-kivy-ios-distribution-on-mac. When(if) I solve it I will post it her too

Comment: kivy-ios is now using clang compiler instead ov llvm-gcc and [all appears to work now](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/63), thanks to [Mathieu Virbel](https://github.com/tito)

Comment: Mattieu is a great guy

Answer (score 1):

iPhone apps must be Objective-C, C, C++ or Objective-C++. They cannot interpret Python code.

*However*, if you have access to the library source, you may be able to translate and then compile the Python source to C code.

I would look into the [PyPy Toolchain](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/translation.html) as a starting point.

Comment: I'm quite certain he isn't looking to just run some Python code in a shell but rather include it in another app.

Comment: we build android apps in python with kivy where I work and it works fine ... I suspect you are right about the ios script thing ... but kivy basically does what he wants (with some limitations)